# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError / Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jar

I have "prog.java" file with main method that uses lib.jar

root folder:

- prog.java
- lib.jar

I do: 
`javac -cp lib.jar prog.java`

now my root folder:
root folder:

- prog.java
- lib.jar
- prog.class
- prog$1.class

now i try to run my program:

```
java -cp lib.jar prog
```

i get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Prog
```

if i do:

```
java prog
```

i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

please help!

Comment: Can you include the code of your file ? Make sure to also include the package name. By the way, your class should have the same name as the file, `Prog.java` and not `prog.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java -cp .:lib.jar prog
```

Note the dot. Also make sure your file name matches the class name. Finally it is better if you make both the class name and file name start with capital letter (convention).

Comment: Thank you. You save my life!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `.class` files to the classpath, too. To do that, you should add the "root" folder containing your compiled classes. Since it looks like your `prog` class is in an unnamed package, just set the classpath to `lib.jar:.` (classpath separator `:` on Linux) or `lib.jar;.` (classpath separator `;` on Windows). The dot `.` means the current directory, which in your case contains the compiled `.class` files.

[Read more about setting the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

NB. - It's always best to put your Java classes in a [named package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html).